# ASP Dropdown list values not accessible on webform server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

so i have a dropdown list in a asp webform. My problem is that when i get the values on server side, the values show as empty or "". I have an exact identical dropdown list in another webform, where it works perfectly. Any of you have an idea why i have this problem?
Here is where i call it on the server side.

```
private void AddHandlingInstructions()
    {
        var handlingInstLang1 = ddNewHandlingInstructions.SelectedItem.Value;
        var handlingInstValue1 = ddNewHandlingInstructionsValue.SelectedItem.Value;

        if (ddNewHandlingInstructions.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            svc.CreateHandlingInstructionsOnTradeItem(handlingInstLang1, handlingInstValue1);
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }           

    }
```

and here is the html for the dropdown list

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddNewHandlingInstructions" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

here is where i databind the list.

```
ddNewHandlingInstructions.DataSource = svc.GetAllLanguageCodes();
        ddNewHandlingInstructions.DataTextField = "option";
        ddNewHandlingInstructions.DataValueField = "value";
        ddNewHandlingInstructions.DataBind();
```

I call the AddHandlingInstructions Method in a button click event.

I have tried changing the id names. Just to see if it was that for some reason, but it had no effect.

Comment: Does you drodownlist contain list items ?

Comment: Have you called `.Databind()` on `ddNewHandlingInstructions` before this piece of code is executed?

Comment: @RahulSingh i call it in a button click event

Comment: @NitinAlapati yes it contains list items. if i look at the drop downlist in chromes web tools i can see that is has values and options.

Comment: @user1429080 yes i databind on pageload and the method is first called when i click the button event

Comment: @RahulSingh i am positive that i only bind the dropdown one time. And that is when the page is loaded

Comment: @KevinJensen - With `!IsPostBack` right? :)

Comment: @RahulSingh yes :) i have an if statment in the page load where i say if(!IsPostback) then databind the controls

Comment: Is `ViewState` enabled on the page? And is the button doing a full post back? Meaning, it's not an `Updatepanel` or a `PageMethod` or some other partial post/call back?

Comment: @user1429080 yes it is a full postback. It redirect after i saves the data. ViewState i just the default option, i dont know if that is enabled then?

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatch in your code

You call `addHandlingInstructions` but your ddl is identified with `ddNewHandlingInstructions`

Your text : I call the addHandlingInstructions in a button click event.

Comment: i have changed the text. I can see it was confusing the way that i explained it. But the ddNewHandlingInstructions is the id of the dropdownlist. And the AddHandlingInstructions is a method that is called in the click event. And in the AddHandlingInstructions method i call the dropdownlist that with the id  ddNewHandlingInstructions. Hope this explaines it better.